# JsonException: Invalid character '.' in input string (Unity)

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, assets

```
 public string VERSION = null;
void LoadVersion()
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    string full_path = string.Format("{0}/version", Application.streamingAssetsPath);
    string jsonString;

    // Android only use WWW to read file
    WWW reader = new WWW(full_path);
    while (!reader.isDone) { }

    jsonString = reader.text;
    JsonData itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsonString);
#else
    string path = string.Format("{0}/version", Application.streamingAssetsPath);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    VERSION = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    reader.Close();
#endif
}
```

I'm having a trouble on this for 6 hours just for this json . Could someone help me please. I don't know why it isn't working .

Comment: Seems like you have a string and at the moment that you are trying to parse or convert that string to a Json object you are getting that exception. The error is about a `.` character, one possible cause is that the string is not a valid json element.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @mayo hmmm i don't still quite get this . Haha i'm sorry. So what should i do?

Comment: @mjwills I'm debugging it on the logcat so it's actually the error is [this](https://imgur.com/a/TMrRL)

Comment: I'm sorry . It's a bit too long so that's why i use an image . Please let me just for this time .

Comment: So, seems like the method `LoadVersion` load a file called `version` from the StreamingAssetsFolder (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html), after reading the content of that file, tries to convert the content in a Json object. Seems like the problem is, that the content of that file is not a valid input. (a Json object is a text that follows certain rules). So, you should check the contents of that file, and see if its a valid json object. (for example here https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: the content of my version.file is this 7.001.301.ma.171120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad i didn't scan all the codes on my project i was not suppose to convert it to .json file . I will just read it so basically i will do it like this .

```
 public string VERSION = null;
 void LoadVersion()
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
string full_path = string.Format("{0}/version", Application.streamingAssetsPath);
string jsonString;

// Android only use WWW to read file
WWW reader = new WWW(full_path);
while (!reader.isDone) { }

jsonString = reader.text;

#else
string path = string.Format("{0}/version", Application.streamingAssetsPath);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
VERSION = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
reader.Close();
#endif
}
```

Am i doing it right . i was just supposed to read my version.file